# Raise an event before anybody has subscribed to it

Tags: c#

I would like to raise an event and notify existing subscribers if any exist. But I also expect new subscribers to be notified of all events raised so far as soon as they subscribe. Is this possible out of the box or do I need to implement that functionality myself? Right now my code look like this:

```
public delegate void GridCompiled(int gridsize);
public event GridCompiled OnGridCompiled;

ctor(){
    if (OnGridCompiled != null)
        OnGridCompiled(gridsize);
}
```

If event has 0 subscribers it won't be raised and it also won't be raised for subscribers that subscribe after event has been raised.

In case I need to implement that myself, what are my options?

Comment: Might be an overkill, but Rx.Net is providing a `Replay` method: http://www.introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/14_HotAndColdObservables.html#Replay

Comment: Seems to me like you are looking for a message queue, not for events.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no tracking of raising events, so you would have to implement the functionality yourself. You would need a list to store your previous event arguments in order and execute the related events when a new event listener is added:

```
class Example {
    private readonly List<GridCompiledEventArgs> m_previousEventArgs = new List<EventArgs>();
    private EventHandler<GridCompiledEventArgs> m_gridCompiled;

    public event EventHandler<GridCompiledEventArgs> GridCompiled {
        add {
            //Raise previous events for the caller
            foreach(GridCompiledEventArgs e in m_previousEventArgs) {
                value(this, e);
            }
            //Add the event handler
            m_gridCompiled += value;
        }
        remove {
            m_gridCompiled -= value;
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnGridCompiled(GridCompiledEventArgs e) {
        if (m_gridCompiled != null) {
            m_gridCompiled(this, e);
        }
        m_previousEventArgs.Add(e);
    }
}
```

There are two things you have consider for this solution. If you want to adress them, your solution will become more complex:

1. If `GridCompiledEventArgs` can be changed by an event handler (e.g. to return a status to the caller), the event args will be stored in the previous event list with those changes. Also, if an event handler keeps a reference to the event args they might even change it later. If you don't want that, you have to store a copy in `m_previousEventArgs` and create another copy before you raise the "historic" event.
2. It is best practice to allow derived classes to override the `OnGridCompiled` method instead of handling the event or changing its behavior. If a derived class changes `OnGridCompiled` to intercept the event and not raise it in certain cases, this behavior will not always apply for the "historic" event, since it is raised without `OnGridCompiled` (which might be just the behavior you want). If you want to change that you have to implement a solution that goes through `OnGridCompiled`. If this is an option for you, you can avoid this problem by making the class `sealed` and the `OnGridCompiled` method `private` instead of `protected virtual`.

Comment: Thank you. Point 2 doesn't apply to my case because class is sealed already but I will need to consider point 1. I have one more question though. Why didn't you write `private event EventHandler<GridCompiledEventArgs> m_gridCompiled;`?

Comment: Because it's not an event. `GridCompiled` is the event. `m_gridCompiled` is just the backer field that stores the event handler. The whole construct is called _event method syntaxt_.

Comment: Maybe I should expand on my question. I understand event as list of methods that are called when you raise the event and I thought keyword `event` is essential for this behaviour. But in the example above you can add event handler to `m_gridCompiled` (which is not event) and raise it just as you would raise an event. Is keyword`event` there just for code clarity?

Comment: An event handler is essentially a delegate. Delegates are used for many different purposes (events, callbacks etc.). You could define the event with a delegate, but that would cause different semantics. An event has add/remove semantics. That means you can only add or remove handlers; other operations (like assignments) are not possible. If you don't use `event` you have field/property semantics, which is different.